# What's the best way to model complicated pipes?

Tags: modeling

I've been trying to model a realistic rocket engine and if you've never seen a rocket engine before, they have some really complicated plumbing structure.

[image: Rocket engine plumbing looks something like this]

I've tried getting some crazy shapes using either the Array or Curve modifier but they don't work that well with complicated curves and always produce some weird results. Is there a better way to make a weirdly bent pipe or wire?

Answer (score 0):

first create a circle of 16 vertices or 32 verts (16 its better for less polycount), then convert it to a curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> , then add a bezier curve and set the bevel object to that circle, also if there are too much edge loops reduce the resolution size to 6 or 8, then stretch or shape your curve recording what you want in edit mode.

Comment: Circle object isn't necessary to use circular bevel for the curve, you can just increase Depth without setting any bevel object.

Comment: yes i also though that, that can be done in bevel resolution

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting by adding a bunch of bezier curves.  Do not apply as a mesh until you have all the pipes in and are satisfied with how they look.  In order to add more intricate detail, you will have to apply them as meshes.  Then you can edit the mesh to your heart's content!  BUT!  Be sure to SAVE BACKUPS OF THE BEZIER CURVES!  You never know what will cause you to have to redo the process on at least one of your pipes.  Have fun!